# Unity 3D - Game is fine in "play" but when built, player moves diagonal up+left

Tags: unity, build-process

So I just completed the first "[Roll-a-ball](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/roll-ball-tutorial)" tutorial, but when I run the build, the game ball races to the Upper-Left corner even when I don't press any buttons.

I did the obvious stuff (reboot, build again...) but it still does it for the PC stand-alone build, and not when I play directly from Unity.

My code doesn't seem to be different from the tutorial (see link above).  Here's the input handling code inside of the "PlayerController.cs":

```html
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

 Vector3 movement = new Vector3 (moveHorizontal, 0.0f, moveVertical);

 rb.AddForce (movement * speed);
    }
```

Then I added statements to print the Horizontal and Vertical. When inside the IDE and I play it, they're zero, and when I press an arrow key, they move from 0 to 1 floating point in about a second. In the built stand-alone, Horiz is -1, Vert is 1.

```html
void SetCountText ()
{
    countText.text = 
        "Count: " + count.ToString () + "\n" + 
        "Horizontal: " + Input.GetAxis("Horizontal").ToString() + "\n" +
        "Vertical:" + Input.GetAxis("Vertical").ToString()
        ;
    if (count >= 12) {
        winText.text = "YOU WIN!!";
    }
}
```

[image: Ball in UL corner]

Comment: Take a look at your input handling code, and determine what input is being read when the ball is moving this way. That should help narrow down whether the problem is bad input coming in, or something further down the pipe in your control scripts.

Comment: The next part of my question was asking you to determine whether those Input.GetAxis(...) calls are returning strange values in the built game, and what those values are.

Comment: Okay, but the problem doesn't happen in your IDE, right? It's in the built game. So that's where you need to examine the values.

Comment: So I dove down the rabbit hole of "how the heck do I know where the signal is coming from" - it looks like the answer is that I can't without some 3rd party help?  https://feedback.unity3d.com/suggestions/scripting-expose-input-manager-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after a lot of digging and trying random things, I found out that it's my 3DMouse driver.  Even when I didn't have the spacenavigator plugged in, there was something that Unity was seeing.

[image]

I fixed the issue in settings by unchecking all of the axis.

[image]